# Scala Class: 'Test class should have exactly one public constructor'

Tags: scala, ant, junit, build.xml

I am trying to run a Scala class in an `ant` builder using JUnit testing framework.

**TestFile**:

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert._

class MyTests{
  def helperfunction1() = //implementation
  def helperfunction2() = //implementation

  @Test
  def testExamples() = {
  //testing stuff
  }

}
```

**Ant XML build.xml file**

```
. . . . 
<target name="run-tests">
 <junit>
  <include name="**/*Tests.class" />
 </junit>
</target>
. . . .
```

I get this error when I try running run_test:

```
[junit] java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public constructor
. . . . (further stacktrace)
[junit] Method testExamples() should not be static
[junit] java.lang.Exception: Method testExamples() should not be static
. . . . (further stacktrace)
```

I do not understand what I might be doing wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: Your 'Class' declaration keyword should be lowercase. Typo ?